# Python package - aiohttp has a warning message "Unclosed client session"

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

My code is as follows:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

urls = [
    'http://www.163.com/',
    'http://www.sina.com.cn/',
    'https://www.hupu.com/',
    'http://www.csdn.net/'
]

async def get_url_data(u):
    """
    read url data
    :param u:
    :return:
    """
    print('running ', u)
    resp = await aiohttp.ClientSession().get(url=u)
    headers = resp.headers
    print(u, headers)
    return headers


async def request_url(u):
    """
    main func
    :param u:
    :return:
    """
    res = await get_url_data(u)
    return res

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task_lists = asyncio.wait([request_url(u) for u in urls])
loop.run_until_complete(task_lists)
loop.close()
```

When i running my code, it's display a warning message: 
**Unclosed client session**

Anybody can give me some solutions about that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 29):

You should close the connection in the end.
You have 2 options:

You can close the connection manually:

```
import aiohttp
session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
# use the session here
session.close()
```

Or you can use it with a contex manager:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(client):
    async with client.get('http://python.org') as resp:
        assert resp.status == 200
        return await resp.text()

async def main(loop):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as client:
        html = await fetch(client)
        print(html)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

> The client session supports the context manager protocol for self closing.

Comment: re the manual option, should that be `await session.close()` ?

Comment: Yes, the `session.close()` is a coroutine and thus simply using `session.close()` will do nothing

Answer (score 13):

If you are not using context manager, the proper way to close it would also need an `await`. Many answers on the internet miss that part, and few people actually notice it, presumably because most people use the more convenient context manager. But the manual `await session.close()` is essential when/if you are closing a class-wide session inside the `tearDownClass()` when doing `unittest`ing.

```py
import aiohttp
session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
# use the session here
await session.close()
```

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to add await to the session.close() because I am in an async function.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `ClientSession` using async context manager for proper blocking/freeing resources:

```
async def get_url_data(u):
    """
    read url data
    :param u:
    :return:
    """
    print('running ', u)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        resp = await session.get(url=u)
        headers = resp.headers
        print(u, headers)
        return headers
```