# im trying to build a lyrics command with discord.py and i get this error.Any ideas on what i did wrong an how can i fix it?

Tags: discord, discord.py, aiohttp

```py
@commands.command()
async def lyrics(self,ctx,artist, title):
        cs = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        res = await cs.get('https://api.lyrics.ovh/v1/{}/{}'.format(artist,title))
        data = await res.json()
        data = ['lyrics']
        await ctx.send(data)
```

i get this error.idk what i did wrong.its my first time using aiohttp so im getting a little confused.

```
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x00000218657B6160>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x0000021865678A70>, 379071.609)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x00000218657B6E10>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your traceback says, and as written on [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112848/python-package-aiohttp-has-a-warning-message-unclosed-client-session), the connector should be closed before the program stops. I assume you get this error at the end of the lifetime of your program. Try using `cs.close()` just before the program finishes to see if it goes away